# Conditional Operator, is it appropriate?

Tags: operators, conditional-statements

I'm wondering, when is it appropriate to use conditional operators?

I've found I can use them an awful lot, and it really shortens the number of lines in my project but I worry that it makes my code harder to read for people I work with.

I know there's quite a few coding standard formats that people stick to and I was wondering if they made any mention of the use of conditional operators.

```
(a == b) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Yes, there are some coding standards that avoid it and some that worship it. Just search the web for them!

Comment: Never ever use boolean literals in the body of a conditional.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I'll be sure not to in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of Googling, you should know that this is often called the ternary operator.

Myself, I like them when they are short

```
      var quantity_message =  qty > 7 ? "enough" : "insufficient";
```

But I think they get hard to read very quickly as they get longer.

The common conventions such as the [official Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) or [Google's java conventions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) do not talk about whether to use ternary expressions, but have some comments on how to format them.  I don't think anyone would ban them outright, but I'd be judicious.